# How to parse a sequence of commands line in the same way bash would?

Tags: java, string, parsing, tokenize

#### Input

I have the following example input (each of those is a bash executable command):

```
client-properties create mode "publisher" "version" "mode"
client-properties set "publisher" "version" "mode" "prop1" "value
value
value"
client-properties set "publisher" "version" "mo\"de" "prop2" "שלום עליכם"
```

#### Output

From that, I want to parse it into 3 `String[]`s as follows:

```
{"client-properties", "create", "mode", "publisher", "version", "mode"}
{"client-properties", "set", "publisher", "version", "mode", "prop1", "value\nvalue\nvalue"}
{"client-properties", "set", "publisher", "version", "mo\"de", "prop2", "שלום עליכם"}
//                                                   (mo"de)
```

#### Requirements

The hard requirements are as follows:

- Newlines denote new statements.
- Spaces denote single arguments.
- Arguments delimited by double quotes (`"`) are considered a single argument even if it has spaces or newlines
- The `\"` escape sequence may be used to insert a literal double quote in an argument
- Unicode characters are allowed (assuming UTF8 is safe).

#### What I've tried

I've looked into regular expressions, but it got very complicated, very fast. I've looked into [`StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) (Which appears very primitive) and [`StreamTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html) (Which doesn't handle unicode very well).

I would like to avoid writing a parser by hand if possible.

Any ideas with regards to this? My latest attempt is as follows:

```
public static List<String> tokenize(String s) {
    List<String> opts = new ArrayList<>();
    try (StringReader sr = new StringReader(s)) {
        StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(sr);
        st.resetSyntax();
        // From      ! to end of ascii range. But alas, no unicode
        st.wordChars(31, 127);
        st.quoteChar('\"');
        st.whitespaceChars(32, 32);
        while (st.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
            opts.add(st.sval);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {}

    return opts;
}
```

Comment: You'll need custom parsing. You're very close to CSV format so possibly you may find a public CSV lib which can match your spec. I would mostly worry about escaping the quote.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Not exactly. I don't have a predetermined number of columns, or headers.

Comment: Have you already looked into CSV libs? I don't remember any one requiring a predetermined number of columns. It's usually an additional option.

Comment: Should `\uHEXA` be treated as six separate characters ``\`` `u` `H` `E` `X` `A` , or one character where `HEXA` is its index in Unicode Table?

Comment: Six separate characters. Someone else parses the actual arguments and does stuff with them, but this is passed into a CommandLineParser (think `main (String ...args)` and so they need to be passed as they were inputted. (Of course, that would appear as `\uHEXA` in the input file, and as a Java string, `"\\uHEXA"`

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `opencsv` library, imported using `gradle` like:

```
compile 'net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:3.4'
```

Try something similar to following program:

```
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    private static final char SEPARATOR = ' ';
    private static final char QUOTE_CHAR = '"';
    private static final char ESCAPE = '\\';

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<String[]> result = new ArrayList<>();

        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(
                new FileReader(args[0]),
                SEPARATOR,
                QUOTE_CHAR,
                ESCAPE);

        result.addAll(reader.readAll());

        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result.get(i)));
        }

    }

}
```

That yields:

```
[client-properties, create, mode, publisher, version, mode]
[client-properties, set, publisher, version, mode, prop1, value
value
value]
[client-properties, set, publisher, version, mo"de, prop2, שלום עליכם]
```

Comment: This actually looks very promising! Thanks! I'll see if I can integrate that idea and accept if I do.